# How to use "scrollIntoView()" in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, protractor, ui-automation

I am currently working on the automation of angular js application ..
We are currently using typescript for the automation language.
I want to scroll to an element and then click on the particular element.

```
 var element = element(by.className('learn-link'));
 browser.driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element); element.click();
```

I want to know if this is the correct method for scrollIntoView() the element .

Answer (score 0):

```
const element: ElementFinder = element(by.className('learn-link'));
await browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", element);
await element.click();
```

remember that for using `await` for resolving promises your function should be `async`.

```
async someFunction() {
await ...
}
```